My header.php file can`t see the scss file and I do not know how to solve it
my project\header.php looks like this way
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Understrap
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

$bootstrap_version = get_theme_mod('understrap_bootstrap_version', 'bootstrap4');
$navbar_type = get_theme_mod('understrap_navbar_type', 'collapse');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php understrap_body_attributes(); ?>>
    <?php do_action('wp_body_open'); ?>
    <div class="site" id="page">

        <!-- ******************* The Navbar Area ******************* -->
        <!-- Logo creating -->
        <header id="wrapper-navbar">
            <div class="top-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-7">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <a class="skip-link <?php echo understrap_get_screen_reader_class(true); ?>" href="#content">
                <?php esc_html_e('Skip to content', 'understrap'); ?>
            </a>
            <?php get_template_part('global-templates/navbar', $navbar_type . '-' . $bootstrap_version); ?>
        </header><!-- #wrapper-navbar -->

Somehow it does not read the .scss files in the project\scr\sass
I'm basically try to working with this sample https://github.com/understrap/understrap
But it seems something I'm not doing well. Could anyone help me please.
Sass, node, npm etc are all installed. And I was trying follow this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLhnubqavDg     (it is around at at 20min

Welcome! Nowhere in this file are you trying to link to a CSS file. Maybe it's happening with something that's hooking into the wp_head action, but we can't tell. Also, we are not going to watch a YouTube tutorial video. Start from the beginning of your tutorial until you see what went wrong.

okay I try... thanks :)
